# Capturing Client Machine time in web applications

Tags: javascript, vs-web-application-project

We are currently developing a Web Application for one of our clients who is interested in selling it across continents. Now one of the features of the web application requires the application to capture the local time of the machine the client is using. I have looked for various options on the forum and using javascript seems to be the only option. Now the question is what happens when a user has javascript disabled on his machine.

Is there any better alternative for this since this is paramount for the application to capture the client machine time/ date.

Eagerly awaiting a response.

Comment: no, but the number of people with javascript disabled is absolutely negligible.

Answer (score 0):

there is no real way to get the exact user time without javascript... I mean if the user disables javascript you could try to get the user location from IP and then set the correct time in your DB.

I would suggest you to offer a possibility to change the user time zone so the user can set up the correct time in the settings.